# CreateFile with FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING but not FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH

Tags: windows, createfile

Is it valid to call [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) with the `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` flag but without the `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` flag? In what situations will this usage be considered useful?

`FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` indicates the OS shouldn't buffer the data, but the absence of `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` indicates the OS shouldn't write through to the disk. These seem like conflicting requirements, how can the OS not buffer and not write-through?

Comment: this is valid. absence of `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` nothing indicates.

Comment: Does `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` automatically imply `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` ?

Comment: yes, this is correct

Comment: i be say `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` have sense only in case buffered io. in case `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` used - this flag lost sense (exist or no - no different)

Comment: As noted in [File Caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/file-caching): File system metadata is always cached. Therefore, to store any metadata changes to disk, the file must either be flushed or be opened with `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH`.

Answer (score 0):

According to a [recent Microsoft blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20210729-00/?p=105494), the `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` flag "[tells] the disk controller to flush the data out of its internal cache."

The table at the bottom of that post further clarifies that there is "no hardware flush" when `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` is set without `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH`.

Also, as Eryk Sun previously noted in a comment, `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` is not documented to immediately write file metadata to disk, whereas `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` is documented to immediately write file metadata to disk. This makes sense because the focus of `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` is to avoid copying of file data into OS-owned buffers, which seems an unreasonable goal for file system metadata since that would necessitate restricting file systems to one specific, publicly defined on-disk layout of file metadata.